# How to remove border from button control and set checkbox background

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I am a beginner in win32 API and I made

```
HWND button = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_BITMAP, 150, 100, 150, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, hInstance, NULL);
```

and

```
HWND check = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX, 150, 100, 300, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_CHECK, hInstance, NULL);
```

I want to remove white border from button control to which I inserted a bitmap and set black background and white text on `BS_CHECKBOX`. I read about `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: I believe you need to make an owner drawn button. Similar: [Remove border from win32 button](//stackoverflow.com/q/20443608)

Comment: I saw this solution but I don't know how to apply it in the checkbox. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WM_CTLCOLORBTN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-ctlcolorbtn) should be used with [BS_OWNERDRAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/button-styles).

That is to say, only when `BS_OWNERDRAW` is added, the `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` will be triggered and the button can be redrawn.

But when you use `BS_OWNERDRAW`, your original checkbox style will be replaced, like this.

```
check = CreateWindowEx(0,L"BUTTON",L"text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX | BS_OWNERDRAW, 150, 100, 60, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CHECK, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);
 case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
{
    return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    break;
}
case WM_DRAWITEM:
{
    LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (pDIS->hwndItem == check)
    {
        SetTextColor(pDIS->hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetBkColor(pDIS->hDC, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        WCHAR Text[99];
        int len = SendMessage(check, WM_GETTEXT,
            ARRAYSIZE(Text), (LPARAM)Text);
        TextOut(pDIS->hDC, pDIS->rcItem.left, pDIS->rcItem.top, Text, len);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Debugging results：

[image: debug result]

You'll find that it's different from what you think.

> According to MSDN,creates an owner-drawn button. The owner window
>   receives a WM_DRAWITEM message when a visual aspect of the button has
>   changed. Do not combine the BS_OWNERDRAW style with any other button
>   styles.

So, I suggest you do that.

```
check = CreateWindowEx(0,L"BUTTON",L"text123", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX ,150, 100, 60, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CHECK, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)lParam;
    if (hWnd == check)
    {
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    }
break;
}
```

By triggering `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`, the text and background colors are self-drawn.

[image: Debug result]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It’s very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Strive answer doesn't work with buttons. Seems like it works only with text boxes and checkboxes.
Btw here still border's on it.

You should create buttons in this way:

```
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

 CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "Button", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_FLAT | BS_OWNERDRAW, start_x, start_y, size_y, size_x, hWnd, (HMENU)(i + 2000), NULL, NULL);
```

.

```
case WM_DRAWITEM: {
            auto id = LOWORD(wParam);
            if (id >= 2000) {
                id -= 2000;
                drawButton(dis, id);
                return true;
            }


case WM_INITDIALOG: {
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icx;
    icx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icx.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icx);
```